# Design small company website in using office 365 sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, design, architecture

Looking design architecture and idea to *Design small company website* in using office 365 sharepoint online.

- Time sheet (employee time entery)
- Employee information
- Leave request management

Without using third party solution, if some one already implemented please do let me know thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a vague and broad question?  It seems like you have a lot of reading and research and perhaps training to do?

So, here's something to get you started on reading and research.  The SP Maven is a useful and practical resource.  This [link filters on intranet](https://sharepointmaven.com/?s=intranet&post_type=post), while you'll have some [Information Architecture](https://sharepointmaven.com/category/information-architecture/) to read up on too.

Good luck!